# C++ template explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I have working code like this.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
   template<typename T>
   void foo(T val);
};

template<typename T> void A::foo(T val)
{
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

// link template "against" int
template void  A::foo(int val);

// #include header here

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo(12);
}
```

Template is in separate CPP file, but linking works, because of explicit instantiation:

```
template void  A::foo(int val);
```

Then I did some re-factoring, and code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename G>
struct A{
   template<typename T>
   void foo(T val);
};

template<typename G>
template<typename T> void A<G>::foo(T val)
{
  std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

// link template "against" int - not working
//template<typename G>
//template void A<G>::foo(int val);

int main(){
    A<float> a;
    a.foo(12);
}
```

How can I "link" T=int, but keep G "unknown"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called explicit instantiation.

You can't do this, because `G` is unknown and it is not a single type. It is rather a set of types.

Comment: @Nick yes, syntax is pretty tricky in such case. See https://gist.github.com/artemkin/61d919c6da3fa2d63833

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this. To actually produce a code from a template (I guess that's what you call *link*), the compiler need to know *all* the template parameters.

So you are left with the standard options for template instantiation: either explicitly tell the compiler what `T` and `G` will be used, either let the compiler see full code for the template member wherever you use it (that is, include the code in header).

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR you can't*.

In your case I'd just specify the type you intend to use

```
template void A<float>::foo(int val);
```

or (rather bulky) explicitly instantiate **all** the types `G` could be used for.

There is no way you can explicitly instantiate the template if `G` cannot be deduced.

Notice that linking works not because this syntax is a linker command but because your compiler is producing code that is later found at link-time. See more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation)